Is it generally acceptable to answer a question that has an accepted answer?
Some questions continue to percolate even though they have an accepted answer. Is it generally O.K. to enter an on topic response afterwards?

Thanks. I'm enjoying the site. Nice job.

Usually I don't accept answers until I feel the topic is closed. But things tend to change over time and a better/more precise or more up to date answer can hopefully emerge. So yes it is OK to answer questions with accepted answers.

Yes!
Assuming, of course, that you've something useful to add. "Accepted" just means the person who asked the question found the answer helpful - it doesn't mean that answer is necessarily the last word on the topic. If you think you can provide a better answer, or even just answer from a different perspective, then by all means - post it!

I think this differs from my perspective.  Seeing a "check" next to the answer is usually an indicator that the asker has said "okay, thanks for answering me, I'm good!"  Otherwise, by definition, there is always a "best" answer from the list (that is, a question with just one answer has that as the best question) and the tag becomes meaningless (IMHO)

Sure - but just because one user (albeit the one who asked the question) is satisfied with it doesn't mean every future reader will be. The whole point of SE is that questions tend to be had by multiple people - a future reader with the same problem may well find your answer more useful. That doesn't mean every question needs loads of answers... But if you see an opportunity to expand on the knowledge provided, you're more than welcome to do so.

As Shog9 and Joe state (and demonstrate): Yes, there's nothing wrong with adding a useful answer to a question that already has an accepted answer - indeed I remember there being a discussion about how we could tactfully suggest that new users don't accept answers straight away on SO, because seeing that a question already had an accepted answer was perceived as discouraging others from answering.
It's also useful when technology or techniques have moved on - especially on programming sites where questions might be about Beta software, but even here, if the LEGO Group were to release a new brick that makes a particular form of SNOT building easier, then by all means post more answers about it.
Generally though, usually it's just people saying "Thanks that helped me too" because they can post an answer with no rep, but can't add a comment.
